# How to set up cron job in MySQL for windows server

Tags: php, scheduler

How to set up cron job in MySQL for windows server?
The purpose is for sending a reminder mail.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Windows Task Scheduler via `Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks` or [`SchTasks.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which is a CLI to Scheduled Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows Service. Windows service will run like a cron job.

Comment: tanx Gijo George that helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

cron job is specific to *nix based os for windows windows scheduler will be there

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

follow this link for more details